# JSF2: Tag Library supports namespace: http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/components/customer, but no tag was defined for name: list

Tags: jsf-2, mojarra

I created a composite component for a list of customers. I can use this component in a view:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
  xmlns:customer="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/components/customer">

<ui:composition template="/WEB-INF/templates/template.xhtml">

  <ui:define name="caption">
    <h:outputText value="#{msg.customerListHeading}" />
  </ui:define>

  <ui:define name="content">

    <ui:decorate template="/WEB-INF/templates/sidebox.xhtml">
      <ui:param name="title" value="#{msg.customerListHeading}" />

      <p:outputPanel>
        <h:form id="customerList">

          <customer:list list="#{customerControllerBean.list}">
            <f:facet name="headerButton">
              <h:button outcome="customerdetail.jsf"
                value="#{msg.newButtonLabel}" />
            </f:facet>
            <f:facet name="rowButton">
              <h:commandButton value="#{msg.deleteButtonLabel}"
                action="#{customerControllerBean.delete(customer)}" />
              <h:button outcome="customerdetail.jsf?id=#{customer.id}"
                value="#{msg.editButtonLabel}" />
            </f:facet>
          </customer:list>

        </h:form>
      </p:outputPanel>
    </ui:decorate>

  </ui:define>

</ui:composition>

</html>
```

But when i use the component in a very similar view i get the following error:

```
<customer:list> Tag Library supports namespace: http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/components/customer, but no tag was defined for name: list
```

The problematic view looks as follows:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
  xmlns:customer="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/components/customer">

<ui:composition template="/WEB-INF/templates/template.xhtml">

  <ui:define name="caption">
    <h:outputText value="#{msg.customerListHeading}" />
  </ui:define>

  <ui:define name="content">

    <ui:decorate template="/WEB-INF/templates/sidebox.xhtml">
      <ui:param name="title" value="#{msg.customerListHeading}" />

      <p:outputPanel>
        <h:form id="customerList">

          <customer:list list="#{customerControllerBean.list}">
            <f:facet name="rowButton">
              <h:commandButton value="#{msg.applyButtonLabel}"
                action="#{orderControllerBean.setCustomer(customer)}" />
            </f:facet>
          </customer:list>

        </h:form>
      </p:outputPanel>
    </ui:decorate>

  </ui:define>

</ui:composition>

</html>
```

As u can see the two view differs only by the facets i use to add buttons to the customer list table as i use the list in two different contexts. But why does the second view not work?

I found that there is/was an issue with Mojarra, but i use the so called stable revision regarding this problem:

```
2012-09-16 19:09:41,512 INFO     [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (MSC service thread 1-4) Mojarra 2.1.7-jbossorg-1 (20120227-1401)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i found a workaround for this problem on Mojarra Jira: 
http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-2437

i placed the `xmlns:customer="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/components/customer"` in the `ui:composition` tag and the view rendered sucessfully:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
  xmlns:customer="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/components/customer">

<ui:composition template="/WEB-INF/templates/template.xhtml" xmlns:customer="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/components/customer">

  <ui:define name="caption">
    <h:outputText value="#{msg.customerListHeading}" />
  </ui:define>

  <ui:define name="content">
```

...

According to that Jira the problem is fixed in Mojarra 2.1.10, so i hope JBoss updates AS 7.1 soon... :)

Answer (score -1):

Incorrect folder path (components) is viewed by eclipse

Remove src/main/resource from build path -- Build Path==> Remove from Build Path.
And add again in build path